# Error 'EC2' object has no attribute 'instances' in the aws lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

After testing this code, I get this error:

```
'EC2' object has no attribute 'instances': AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 11, in lambda_handler
instances=ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filters)
AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'instances'
```

Line 11 is the last line in the code bellow

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    filters = [{ 'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}]
    instances=ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filters)
```

Where exactly is the error here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`EC2.Client.describe_instances()`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) method:

```
instances=ec2.describe_instances(Filters=filters)
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to [Leon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40653079/4486653) you can use the [`EC2.ServiceResource`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#service-resource) class:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=region)
```

Because calling `ec2.instances.filter()` has the benefit of returning a list of resources [`list(ec2.Instance)`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#instance) (instead of a `dict`), on which you can call methods like `start()`, `stop()`, etc. directly:

```
filters = [{ 'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}]
instances=ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filters)

for instance in instances:
    instance.stop()
```